# SQL how to find the first non null value between 2 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given two tables

```
partner

ID | name
----------
 1 | NULL
 2 |  bob
 3 |  C
 4 | tom

partner  history 
ID | name
----------
 1 | joe
 2 |  bob
 3 |  C
 4 | NULL
```

I want to get the first non-null value of the column name.

```
SELECT ???? as name FROM partner p  FULL JOIN partner_history ph ON p.idPartner = ph.idPartner
```

Comment: `SELECT ISNULL(p.name, ph.name) AS name`?

Comment: You want `IS NOT NULL` and `ORDER BY ID`

Comment: @ Lukasz Szozda no its doesn't work returns a long list of non-null names ignoring id. The closet i got so far is by SELECT TOP 1 CONCAT(p.name , ph.name) as name FROM partner p  FULL JOIN partner_history ph ON p.idPartner = ph.idPartner ... the problem with that is if both is not null i am getting duplicate name

Comment: Is your data really representative?  Is `id` repeated in the history table?  If so, how do you know what the most recent value is?

Comment: what would the desired output of your query be?

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff I don't need the most recent value.. I need just the name to show some referencing table history. For most recent value history table has REV column that represents a revision number

Comment: @MariaFinkelstein . . . The answer that you accepted is likely to return duplicate rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use COALESCE:

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE(p.name, ph.name) as name 
FROM partner p  
FULL JOIN partner_history ph 
    ON p.idPartner = ph.idPartner
```

Comment: @MariaFinkelstein this solution is partly correct. What if your history table has `null` names?

Comment: @ django-unchained this is a very good question and you made me nervous for a second.  It works fine with null is a string.. let's say someone name partner as null ..

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `coalesce()`:

```
select coalesce(p.name, ph.name)
from partner p outer apply
     (select top (1) ph.*
      from partner_history ph
      where ph.id = p.id
      order by ?  -- some ordering in the case of duplicates?
     ) ph;
```

I don't understand why you would want a `full join` in this case.

Comment: I am unclear on use of `full join` as well. Looks like we need more info on data to answer that question.

Comment: Sorry about that I removed the complexity of the data and tried to show the part I am struggling with

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `not null` condition on `name` for both tables first to return records that don't have nulls in both tables, then do a `coalesce`.

```
select
coalesce(p_name,ph_name) as name
from
(select a.name as p_name, b.name as ph_name from partner a
full outer join 
partner_history b
on a.id=b.id where a.name is not null and b.name is not null order by id)
```